# Stripe | make two payments with one authentication

Tags: stripe-payments, 3d-secure

I have a scenario where the customer wants to rent an apartment and I want to put a hold on the Card for insurance

Therefore, I make two payment intents, the first is to take the money directly, and the second with capture = manual to collect later if needed

But usually, the second paymentIntent fails because the customer's bank asks for 3D secure so I can't collect the money later

What is the best practice to be able to make the second paymentIntent based on the first 3d secure authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the first PaymentIntent, you should pass the `setup_future_usage` [[0]](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create#create_payment_intent-setup_future_usage) parameter and set its value `off_session` and on the second Payment Intent use the `off_session`[[1]](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create#create_payment_intent-off_session) parameter and set its value `true`. This would indicate to the issuing bank that this Payment is happening off-session and might exempt you from 3DS. In the case that the issuing bank still sees (for whatever reason that Stripe doesn’t really control), then you don’t have any other option than to ask the user to come back to your application and do an on-session authentication. You could read more about this [here](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse?platform=web#charge-saved-payment-method).

Comment: thank you this solution worked for me in all cases except cards that Always request  authentication "4000002760003184" in this case we should redirect user to a 3d secure page

Comment: I have another problem. Sometimes the first operation is successful, but the second operation fails because there is not enough money

So is there a way to check the total paid amount before starting the process?

Comment: yes this is the expected behavior for this card "4000002760003184". This is how you can test the case where 3DS is requested by the issuing bank in off-session.